# delayed_job fails jobs when running as a daemon. Runs fine when using rake jobs:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon, delayed-job

I am literally at my wits end with this. I don't understand why it isn't working.

I have made a class, which I call and queue using a rake command. When I run the worker using 'rake jobs:work' and call the command 'rake get_updates', it executes fine.

However, when I run the worker as a daemon (RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start) and call the command 'rake get_updates' it produces an error.

**app/workers/get_updates.rb**

```
class GetUpdates
    def perform

        beginning = Time.now

        include SoapHelper

        require 'nokogiri'
        require 'activerecord-import'

        product_count = 0
        contloop = true

        while(contloop == true) do

            @xml = Nokogiri::XML(get_unsent_data())
            @guid = @xml.xpath('.//Message').attr("Id")
            bulkUpdates = []

            if (@xml.xpath('.//Product').count > 0)

                @xml.xpath('.//Product').each do |p|

                    product_count += 1

                    update = Update.new
                    update.update_type = p.attr("UpdateType")

                    codes = Hash.new

                    p.children().each do |info| 

                        info.xpath('.//ProductCodes/Code').each do |coco|
                            codes[coco.attr("Scheme").to_s] = coco.content
                        end     

                        update.data = p.children().to_xml.to_s

                    end

                    bulkUpdates << update

                end

                if Update.import bulkUpdates

                  acknowledge_soap_receipt(@guid.to_s)

                else

                  puts "Error, data not saved"
                  contloop = false

                end

            else
                contloop = false
            end

        end

        @time = "Time elapsed #{Time.now - beginning} seconds"
        puts "Product Count: #{ product_count }"
        puts @time

    end
end
```

**clockwork.rake**

```
task :get_updates => :environment do

    Delayed::Job.enqueue GetUpdates.new

end
```

**Autoload paths in 'application.rb'**

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/workers)
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/helpers)
```

**The error message when trying to execute the job**

```
Job failed to load: undefined class/module GetUpdates. Handler: "--- !ruby/object:GetUpdates {}\n\n" /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:97:in `rescue in payload_object' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:89:in `payload_object' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:105:in `block in invoke_job' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:102:in `invoke_job' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in run' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:206:in `block in run' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:205:in `run' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:267:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:267:in `reserve_and_run_one_job' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:189:in `block in work_off' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:188:in `times' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:188:in `work_off' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:153:in `block (4 levels) in start' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:152:in `block (3 levels) in start' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:151:in `block (2 levels) in start' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:150:in `loop' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:150:in `block in start' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in add' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block in add' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/worker.rb:149:in `start' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/command.rb:104:in `run' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/command.rb:92:in `block in run_process' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `block in start_proc' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call_as_daemon' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:259:in `start_proc' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:296:in `start' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in start_all' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `fork' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `block in start_all' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:157:in `each' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:157:in `start_all' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:80:in `run' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:197:in `block in run_proc' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:196:in `run_proc' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/command.rb:90:in `run_process' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/command.rb:83:in `block in daemonize' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/command.rb:81:in `times' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/command.rb:81:in `daemonize' bin/delayed_job:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is the app/workers directory in your application $LOAD_PATH?

Comment: I was under the impression that anything within 'app' was auto-loaded.

Comment: That's an incorrect impression.

Comment: It would seem so. I've added it and it now seems to load fine and outputs that simple puts statement. However when I add the logic for the method, it produces the same 'undefined class/module GetUpdates'.

Comment: What's the logic? Also, how did you add it to the load path?

Comment: I've included some of it, and the load paths, in the op. I can't copy it directly as it's sensitive. I think it's probably the include / require statements that are causing the issues. How would you go about loading those?

Answer (score 5):

Try loading the class in an initializer:

```
# in config/initializers/delayed_job.rb
require 'get_updates'
```

That should make it available to the job.

Comment: Does this file have to be called "delayed_job.rb"? I tried following similar instructions with no luck, but my file was called custom.rb in the same folder. I can't find any documentation that says it has to be named a certain way, so I thought I would ask here.